# Android Studio Java: setSystemUIVisibility cannot resolve symbol view

Tags: java, android, ionic-framework, capacitor

I'm developing an app using [Capacitor js](https://capacitorjs.com/) and trying to achieve an edge-to-edge display on Android. Unfortunately it looks like this requires knowledge about Android Studio and Java that I just don't have so I'm finding myself quite confused.

[image]

I found [this documentation page](https://developer.android.com/training/gestures/gesturenav#java), which tells me that to remove the black bar at the bottom of the screen I can either:

Add the following to my app styles:

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="...">
    <item name="android:navigationBarColor">@android:color/transparent</item>

    <!-- Optional, but recommended for full edge-to-edge rendering -->
    <item name="android:statusBarColor">@android:color/transparent</item>
</style>
```

Which I've added in `res/values/styles.xml`, but which doesn't seem to be doing anythin (the black gesture bar is still there):

```
   <style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
        <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
        <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
        <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
        <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>
        <item name="android:navigationBarColor">@android:color/transparent</item>

        <!-- Optional, but recommended for full edge-to-edge rendering -->
        <item name="android:statusBarColor">@android:color/transparent</item>
    </style>
```

Or, do it programmatically by calling:

```
view.setSystemUiVisibility(View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_HIDE_NAVIGATION
        | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_STABLE);
```

I tried to add the above code to my `MainActivity.java` like this:

```
import android.os.Bundle;

import com.getcapacitor.BridgeActivity;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;

public class MainActivity extends BridgeActivity {
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        view.setSystemUiVisibility(View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_HIDE_NAVIGATION
                | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_STABLE);
    }
}
```

Unfortunately Android Studio is telling me that it `cannot resolve symbol 'view'`.  I understand why that's happening since I have no reference to `view` in my class, but I'm unsure on *how* to get a reference to `view` at all.

I'm sure this can't be that complex, I'm just having a hard time understanding Android Studio and Java as I have very little experience with them. If anyone could point me in the right direction that would be great.

EDIT: Or is `setSystemUI` deprecated? Should I use [this instead](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/WindowInsetsController)? I'm really lost

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `decorView()` from your activity. `View view = getWindow().getDecorView()`. Also, note that this view can be null, so always check for `null` before using it.

> Retrieve the top-level window decor view (containing the standard
> window frame/decorations and the client's content inside of that),
> which can be added as a window to the window manager.

Comment: So I did that, and while the code compiles the gesture bar doesn't seem to be affected. any idea why?

Comment: Try out these flags: `view.setSystemUiVisibility(View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_HIDE_NAVIGATION or View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_FULLSCREEN);`

Comment: `SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_HIDE_NAVIGATION` hides navigation rather than making it transparent, but it does work

Comment: If it works for you, how about upvoting or accepting the answer to help others.

Comment: Well I'm not looking to hide it, I need to make it transparent so it's not what I was looking for.